# On Adding Emgu.CV.World dll showing Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine

I am willing to use FaceTracker Sample [this](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/35284) i.e., added Emgu.CV.World dll in project then it showing me.

> ```
> Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the
> ```
>
> module cannot be loaded.
>
> ```
>   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (bool)
>
>   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>
>   at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.Type extensionType)
> ```
>
> [0x00000] in :0
>
> ```
>   at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespace (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000]
> ```
>
> in :0
>
> ```
>   at Mono.CSharp.GlobalRootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>
>   at Mono.CSharp.Driver.LoadReferences () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>
>   at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>
>   at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>
> The following assembly referenced from E:\Unity 5.2 Projects\OpenCV
> ```
>
> Demos\OpenCVBasedPackages\Assets\Plugins\Emgu.CV.World.dll could not
>   be loaded:
>            Assembly:   System.Drawing    (assemblyref_index=3)
>            Version:    2.0.0.0
>            Public Key: b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>       The assembly was not found in the Global Assembly Cache, a path listed in the MONO_PATH environment variable, or in the location of
>   the executing assembly (E:\Unity 5.2 Projects\OpenCV
>   Demos\OpenCVBasedPackages\Assets\Plugins).
>
> ```
> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
> ```
>
> dependencies.
>       The class Emgu.CV.Mat could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       The class Emgu.CV.Mat could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       The class Emgu.CV.Mat could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       The class ImageGeneratorOutputMode could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       The class OpenNIDataType could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       The class DeviceType could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       The class Emgu.CV.Matrix`1 could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       The class Emgu.CV.Mat could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       The class DebuggerProxy could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       The class Emgu.CV.Matrix`1 could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       The class Emgu.CV.CvArray`1 could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       The class Emgu.CV.Image`2 could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       The class Emgu.CV.Mat could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       The class Emgu.CV.Structure.RotatedRect could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       The class Emgu.CV.Image`2 could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       The class Emgu.CV.Cuda.GpuMat`1 could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>       The class <>c__DisplayClass1 could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       The class <>c__DisplayClass4 could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       The class <>c__DisplayClass7 could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       The class <>c__DisplayClassa could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       The class <>c__DisplayClassd could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       The class <>c__DisplayClass10 could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       The class <>c__DisplayClass13 could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       The class <>c__DisplayClass16 could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World, Version=3.1.0.2282, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7281126722ab4438
>       The class <>c__DisplayClass1 could not be loaded, used in Emgu.CV.World,

I google found lots of answer but nothing work for me i guess it is dll compatible issue? what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Library is compatible to Unitys Version of Mono.
You might need to change the API Compatibility Layer from *.NET 2.0 Subset* **to** *.NET 2.0*? You will find that under **Edit -> Project Settings -> Player -> Other Settings**.

Comment: No. EmguCV usues System.Drawing to draw stuff, and this assembly is not supported in Unity3D. I don't even know how it could be supported. EmguCV as is, is not applicable to Unity3D and I already told that to OP.

Comment: Oh ok, that's bad, the emgu guys made a version for Unity available in the Asset Store  but only under commercial license :/